# Compiler errors with incorrect use of nullptr

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, ubuntu-18.04, nullptr

I am trying the solution provided in this SO Q/A[Compiler error while using shared_ptr with a pointer to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652188/compiler-error-while-using-shared-ptr-with-a-pointer-to-a-pointer) and I am not able to use the solution provided in a proper way. I still get compilation errors on Ubuntu 18.04 with g++ version 7.3

Here is my minimum complete verifiable example to reproduce the problem

test.h

```
# include <memory> 
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::unique_ptr;
struct DataNode
{
 shared_ptr<DataNode> next;
} ;


struct ProxyNode
{
 shared_ptr<DataNode> pointers[5];
} ;


struct _test_
{
  shared_ptr<shared_ptr<ProxyNode>> flane_pointers;
};
```

test.cpp

```
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include "test.h"


 shared_ptr<DataNode> newNode(uint64_t key);
 shared_ptr<ProxyNode> newProxyNode(shared_ptr<DataNode> node);
 struct _test_ test1;
 int main(void)
 {

   test1.flane_pointers(nullptr);
   shared_ptr<DataNode> node = newNode(1000);
 }

 shared_ptr<ProxyNode> newProxyNode(shared_ptr<DataNode> node) {

 shared_ptr<ProxyNode> proxy(new ProxyNode());
 return proxy;
 }


 shared_ptr<DataNode> newNode(uint64_t key) {

 shared_ptr<DataNode> node(new DataNode());
 return node;
 }
```

This is the error I get

```
    test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    test.cpp:11:31: error: no match for call to   ‘(std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<ProxyNode> >) (std::nullptr_t)’
    test1.flane_pointers(nullptr);
                                ^
```

**What else have you tried ?**

I tried initializing the **nullptr** in the header file as well

```
  struct _test_
  {
   shared_ptr<shared_ptr<ProxyNode>> flane_pointers(nullptr);
  };
```

But that did not work either. Where am I going wrong ?

**My Goal**

All I am trying to do is the following - I am trying to initialize flane_pointers which is a vector of pointers to a nullptr. The declaration has been made in a header file as to what type it is and I am trying to initialize it in a .cpp file. While doing that I get the above compilation errors.

```
   flane_pointers(nullptr)
```

**UPDATE**

Could any of the answers explain whether the initialization provided in this [Compiler error while using shared_ptr with a pointer to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652188/compiler-error-while-using-shared-ptr-with-a-pointer-to-a-pointer?noredirect=1&lq=1)  correct or not ?

```
  std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<ProxyNode> > ptr2ptr2ProxyNode(nullptr);
```

To me (and I am a newbie to C++) that initialization looks like a function call as well. Is that incorrect ?

Comment: What are you expecting `test1.flane_pointers(nullptr);` to do? It looks like you're trying to call `flane_pointers` as if it was a function.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz As a newbie to C++ I do not know. I was just trying out the solution given in the linked Q/A.

Comment: @gansub the qusetion you linked to did not suggest `test1.flane_pointers(nullptr);`

Comment: @gansub I downvoted because the code has no comments and when I asked what you were expecting the line of code you asked about to do, you didn't have an answer. A question asking how to do something that doesn't clearly explain what it is you're trying to do is just not a very good question and, IMO, deserves a downvote.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the post has since been updated - you might wanna take a second look (it appears to have added the info you requested earlier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to initialize `flane_pointers` to `nullptr`, you should use initialization of the below form:

```
shared_ptr<shared_ptr<ProxyNode>> flane_pointers = nullptr;
```

in `struct _test_`

or

```
test1.flane_pointers = nullptr;
```

in `main`.

The other form of initialization you are trying to do is interpreted as a function call in `main` and as a function declaration in   `struct _test_`.

In the linked post,

```
 std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<ProxyNode> > ptr2ptr2ProxyNode(nullptr);
```

is in `main` and can only be interpreted as a variable declaration and not a function call because it does not have a function call syntax as the variable is preceded by the type std::shared_ptr >.

To avoid confusion, it is better (from C++11 onwards) to declare and initialize variables with the brace-enclosed initializer `{}`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So can you explain how it works in the linked Q/A ?  std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<ProxyNode> > ptr2ptr2ProxyNode(nullptr)

Comment: If you can tell me which specific line are you referring to in the linked post, I can try to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
test1.flane_pointers(nullptr);
```

You're trying to call `flane_pointers` as though it were a member function. `shared_ptr` can't be called like a function, so you get the compiler error.

If you want to initialize `flane_pointers`, you can just assign to it:

```
test1.flane_pointers = nullptr;
```

Or alternatively, you could do the assignment when you create `test1`:

```
// Initialize test1 with a nullptr
_test_ test1{nullptr};
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
test1.flane_pointers(nullptr);
```

is treated a function call. That's the source of the error. Use assignment instead.

```
test1.flane_pointers = nullptr;
```

And

```
shared_ptr<shared_ptr<ProxyNode>> flane_pointers(nullptr);
```

is not a valid form of in-member initialization. You may use

```
shared_ptr<shared_ptr<ProxyNode>> flane_pointers{nullptr};
```

or

```
shared_ptr<shared_ptr<ProxyNode>> flane_pointers = nullptr;
```